# View width become zero when chain is used in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, android-constraintlayout

I have two `TextView`s that are horizontally chained and displayed in a `DialogFragment`. That two `TextView`'s visiblity set by dynamically, ie, sometimes `tvA` will be visible and sometimes `tvB` or both will display.

> Here is my xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/app_background_color"
android:minWidth="250dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvElement"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/shape_back"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="@string/elements"
    android:textColor="@color/item_view_color"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tvSensor"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvSensor"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/shape_back"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="@string/sensors"
    android:textColor="@color/item_view_color"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tvElement"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/rv_channel"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="62dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_channel"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_ok"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_min="250dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline" />

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_ok"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/global_button_selector_3"
    android:text="@string/ok"
    android:textColor="@drawable/global_button_txt_selector_3"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rv_channel" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

> And the result will be

[image: real device]

> And the layout inspector shows

[image: layout inspector]

> I have two problems
>
> 1. When this code run on a real device the corresponding `TexView`'s width became zero and it is not visible anymore. But when I removed the chain It is working as it is.
> 2. It is based on the `RecyclerView` if it's height given `match_contraints` value it will shrink to the one cell height irrespective of how many items are there, but when I gave `match_parent`, it is wrapped to the items presented in it.

I didn't understand what mistake I have done.

Thanks for your valuable time

Comment: Get rid of the `match_parent` on the `RecyclerView` and make it `0dp`. (`match_parent` in `ConstraintLayout` is frowned upon.) Make sure it has the proper vertical constraints. Also, guidelines cannot be constrained, so get rid of the constraints for the guideline and leave the `62dp`. I think this will help.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, the width don't became zero but your `TextView` s disapear (go to the top out of screen) because they are not linked at the bottom, try by adding `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"` to each TextView

Comment: Try to moove your textviews at the bottom of your XML file, may be they are overlapped by other views

Comment: Can you please look on to the layout inspector? It shows how the items displayed

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/app_background_color"
    android:minWidth="250dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvElement"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_back"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/elements"
        android:textColor="@color/item_view_color"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tvSensor"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSensor"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_back"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/sensors"
        android:textColor="@color/item_view_color"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tvElement"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/rv_channel"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="62dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_channel"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_ok"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_min="250dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_ok"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/global_button_selector_3"
        android:text="@string/ok"
        android:textColor="@drawable/global_button_txt_selector_3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rv_channel" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```